# Encryption, encoding and Python (AES)

Tags: python, encryption, encoding

I'm trying to write an encryption/decryption program called P-Cypher in python (python-Cypher, rhymes with decypher). It uses the PyCrypto libraries to encode a file (using AES). Although I know Python, I do not know cryptography - I'm doing this because I thought it would be fun, so don't critique me on security.

This is how the program is supposed to work.

> 1. Asks for input file.
> 2. Asks whether you want it to encrypt or decrypt. (sets mode)
> 3. Asks for output file. Verifies it exists- if it does not, asks if you want it to create one.
> 4. Encrypts input file and tells you the key/Prompts you for the key, and decrypts the file with the key (Depending on mode)
> 5. Writes to output file.

Everything works except for number 4. (I know step 5 works as step 5 remains pretty much unchanged from the last stable version, v0.03d). On step 4 encoding, one of two things happen depending on which way I code it:

> 1. The thing successfully- YAY! encodes the file. However, the key it prints out is in the form of b'U\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx' like that. When I enter it in step 4 decoding mode, with or without the b and 's, it doesn't work. So the program cannot decrypt the file, rendering half of my program useless.
> 2. I can use .decode(encoding) to turn it into a string. This is the method you see on the code below. However, here is this way's problem- no matter what encoding I use (ascii, ISO, windows-125x, EUR, Big5, utf-8, 16, and 32, etc...) there is always one or more bytes that the encoding cannot encode. And without encoding, there's no decoding, rendering the WHOLE program useless.

So I ask you for help. If you could figure out how to fix problem #1 or #2 (or maybe even both), I would be grateful.

**CODE** -- Updated

```
# P-Cypher-Dev
# Made in 2015 by Mateo Guynn
# v0.04d
# Using AES 16/32/64-bit encryption (Google standard)
# DEV VERSION: Possibly unstable, contains better code.
# Changelog:
"""
v0.02d
- Improved Caesar Cipher
- Added binary Cipher converter (fail)
-------------FILE BROKEN------------
"""
"""
v0.03d
- Added ability to create new output files
- Fixed code not quitting on abort
- DEL : binary Cipher converter 
---------------STABLE---------------

"""
"""
v0.04d
- DEL : Caesar Cypher
- Added 16/32/64-byte AES encryption
- Binary and text now handled in same manner
-------------FILE BROKEN------------
(encryption works, decryption does not)

"""
"""
v0.05d
- Changed AES encryption to Google's way
- Fixed Key entry

"""
import os
import sys
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Util import randpool
import base64
import codecs

MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26 # Shows the number of available characters (26 in the alphabet)

 #NOTES: Binary mode only works if the file is named binary.dat.

def getMode():

    while True:

        eOrD = input('\nDo you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message? ')

        mode = eOrD.lower()

        if mode in 'encrypt e decrypt d'.split():

            return mode

        else:

            sys.exit('\nEnter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d". Capital letters are allowed.\n')



def getMessage():


    inputFile = open(input('\nPlease enter the name of the file you want to encrypt/decrypt. You may use relative or full paths. \nPlease, remember the file extension(s)! ')).read()
    try:
        print ('\nThe contents of the file are: \n%s\n' % inputFile)
        return inputFile
    except IOError as e:
        sys.exit('Unable to open file (the file does not exist or P-Cypher does not have permission to view it).\n Aborting.')
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        sys.exit('Unable to open file (the file does not exist or P-Cypher does not have permission to view it).\n Aborting.')


def getCipher(mode, message):
    block_size = 16 # For AES, this is the only working value
    key_size = 32 # Size of crypto key (possibly changes in getKey())
    aesmode = AES.MODE_CBC # More secure mode
    if mode[0] == 'e':
        key_bytes = randpool.RandomPool(512).get_bytes(key_size)
        open('decryption.key', 'wb+').write(key_bytes)
        print('\nYour keyfile is: decryption.key\n')
        pad = block_size - len(message) % block_size
        data = message + pad * chr(pad)
        iv_bytes = randpool.RandomPool(512).get_bytes(block_size)
        encrypted_bytes = iv_bytes + AES.new(key_bytes,aesmode,iv_bytes).encrypt(data)
        encrypted = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(encrypted_bytes)
        return encrypted
    else: 
        decryptb = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message)
        decrypted_ivbytes = decryptb[:block_size]
        decrypt = decryptb[block_size:]
        print('\nAuto-searching for decryption.key...')
        try:
            key_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(open('decryption.key', 'rb').read())
        except IOError as io:
            key_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(open(input('decryption.key not found. If you have an alternate keyfile, please enter its name now. ')), 'rb').read
        except FileNotFoundError as fnf:
            key_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(open(input('decryption.key not found. If you have an alternate keyfile, please enter its name now. '), 'rb').read())
        decrypted = AES.new(key_bytes, aesmode, decrypted_ivbytes).decrypt(decryptb)
        pad = ord(decrypted[-1])
        decrypted = decrypted[:-pad]
        return decrypted
def getOutput():


    outputFile = input('\nPlease specify an output file. \nDon\'t forget the file extension! ')

    outputCheck = input('\nYour message will be encrypted/decrypted into the following output file: %s\n\nIs this okay? (y/n) ' % outputFile).lower()


    if outputCheck in 'y yes yeah ok'.split():

        try:
            return outputFile
        except IOError as ioerror:
            createNewFile = input('The file you specified does not exist. Shall I create one? (y/n) ')
            if createNewFile in 'y_yes_yeah_yes please_ok'.split('_'):
                oF = open(outputFile, 'w+')
                oF.close()
                return outputFile

            else:
                sys.exit('Aborting...')
    elif outputCheck in 'n no'.split():
        sys.exit('\nAborting...\n')
    else:
        sys.exit('\nAborting.\n')


print("\nP-Cypher Alpha starting up...\n\nv0.05 dev\nMateo Guynn\n2015\n")
mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()

try:
    open(getOutput(), 'wb+').write(getCipher(mode,message))
except IOError:
    sys.exit('Oh noes! Something has gone terribly wrong!')
except FileNotFoundError:
    sys.exit('Your input file was not found.')
print('\nDone.')
```

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to encode it as hex ... this is guaranteed to be ascii characters

```
import codecs
my_key = "U\x22\x54\x33"
print ("Your Key:", codecs.encode(my_key,"hex"))


...

my_decode_key = codecs.decode(input("enter key:"),"hex")
print( repr(my_decode_key))
print( my_decode_key == my_key )
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work. It said 'non-hexadecimal digit found'. Thanks anyways.

Comment: To clarify, the code you posted works. However, when I use codecs.encode on MY code, it gives me that error. Your code just doesn't work on mine.

Comment: any byte string should be hex encodable ... this leads me to believe you are doing something wrong